# ant puts new line at end of manifest

Tags: java, ant, jar, classpath, manifest

I have a jar that uses some of the **apache tomcat** library jars and thus has the following manifest.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Main-Class: foo
    Class-Path: foo.jar foo_utils.jar . /opt/apache-tomcat/
     lib/websocket-api.jar /opt/apache-tomcat/lib/tomcat7-websocket.jar /o
     pt/apache-tomcat/lib/tomcat-util.jar /opt/apache-tomcat/lib/tomcat-co
     yote.jar /opt/apache-tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

The jar is able to find `foo.jar` and `foo_utils.jar` without a problem.

It can't find any of the jars in the `/opt/apache-tomcat/lib` folder. I have checked the path and made sure that it is a valid path to the jars I want and is.due to the ant build puts a new line at the end of the `classpath` last line and thus messes with the line being parsed properly.

How may I have ant not put a new line at the end of my manifest class path file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [JAR File Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html) says (emphasis mine):

> - Class-Path :
>
>   The value of this attribute specifies the **relative** URLs of the extensions or libraries that this application or extension needs.

The presence of a newline at the end of the MANIFEST.MF is not relevant.

Comment: so it has to be relative to where the jar is located basically? I can't put the absolute path in and have the jar find the library from the absolute path?

Comment: @jgr208 Right.  (BTW, if your JAR is running on Tomcat, then this seems like the wrong approach altogether, and you should probably be asking questions about why the Tomcat JARs aren't visible to your JAR.)

Comment: nope not running on tomcat, it is an application that interacts with a tomcat page using websockets so thus needs those packages. hmmm now i need to try and think of the most flexable way to do this build since if someting changes in the future we dont want to have to change a bunch of lines in the build perfectly would be only one line.

Comment: @jgr208 Ok, that makes sense.  In the past, I have had success using the `<manifestclasspath>` element in Ant (http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifestclasspath.html), which will generate a Class-Path with relative paths (e.g., `Class-Path: ../../../opt/apache-tomcat/lib/websocket-api.jar`, etc.), but then the JAR is not relocatable.  You could also consider something like OneJar, or you could build your own class loader infrastructure inside your application, which is obviously non-trivial...

Comment: now to add to the mystery I did `Class-Path: ../../apache-tomcat/lib/websocket-api.jar` and it still says it cant find the jar. So this is getting quirky. Even stopped tomcat to be sure it isnt saying wait these files are in use.

Comment: ok just tried putting the jars in the jar and in the same folder as the jar and still cant find the library that is needed. I am starting to think it is a deeper issue then I originally thought.

Comment: @jgr208 JAR-in-JAR won't work unless you use something like OneJar.  If you put websocket-api.jar in the same directory, then `Class-Path: websocket-api.jar` should work.  If `/test/my.jar`, then `Class-Path: ../opt/apache-tomcat/lib/websocket-api.jar`, for example.

Comment: well now i tried to run the main class in the jar with the `java -cp` command and also manually specified where to find the other jars that are needed. Failed again. So yea I am looking at my build and all and making sure I am not missing something where it compiles correct but is in fact missing something or anything of that nature.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if your manifest file is ending with a new line or carriage return? As per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html - the last line will not be parsed properly if it does not end with a new line or carriage return.

Comment: Yes it does. Hmm but it was built using ant thus I have no control over that.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but that dot between `foo_utils.jar` and `/opt/apache-tomcat/` seems strange to me. Is there a reason for this dot?

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer. However the . tells to also search the current directory as well. This is a unix system also which I forgot to add.

Comment: i am new here and to comment an answer i need 50 reputation, because of this i wrote this as an answer instead of an comment ;)

Comment: You won't get to 50 rep if you're posting comments as answers, so concentrate on giving actual answers first :)